# Why PyCharm does not allow uppercase letters in method naming?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am comfortable with Java naming conventions where you are free to name your methods as long as it starts with lowercase so `methodForTest()` is acceptable.

However, Python (PyCharm IDE) complains for this way and it requires all lowercase.

Why? Can I disable this so I can use uppercase in method naming?

Comment: it complains but does not FORCE you to follow PEP8, however, this is Python, not Java, and PEP8 should be followed as much as possible.

Comment: You can create a method with an uppercase letter. You are just getting a warning because it goes against the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide.

Comment: It's completely allowed. It's just discouraged, like naming a java method `method_for_test`.

Comment: And yes, of course you can configure it.

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153270/how-to-disable-special-naming-convention-inspection-of-pep-8-in-pycharm

Answer (score 14):

Python has *no such limitation*.

Python identifiers must start with an underscore or letter (upper or lowercase), followed by any number of underscores, digits or letters (again, upper or lowercase, doesn't matter); this means an ALL_UPPERCASE name is perfectly valid Python. See the [*Identifiers and keywords*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) section in the reference documentation; Python 3 [expanded on this by allowing a wider range of Unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

However, the widely adopted [PEP 8 Python styleguide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) does have this to say on [naming functions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names):

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

This is a *convention* however, not a syntactic requirement. Perhaps your IDE has a linter installed that warns when you break this convention. You can, if you so wish, ignore it. I note that [PyCharm implements such a check](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2013/02/long-awaited-pep-8-checks-on-the-fly-improved-doctest-support-and-more-in-pycharm-2-7/), for example.

In PyCharm, you can click on the warning icon and tell PyCharm to ignore the class of errors:

[image: PyCharm *Ignore errors like this* option]

Also see the [PyCharm documentation on suppressing inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/suppressing-inspections.html?origin=old_help).

Answer (score 1):

Python is really permissive (too much maybe) and let's you do almost whatever you want.

You can name your classes, methods, variables, the way you want. You can access every variable of an instance, there is not public / private concept.

Pycharm / IntelliJ is just warning you but does not FORCE you to follow PEP8, however, this is Python, not Java, and PEP8 should be followed as much as possible.

Python is all about ***readability over fanciness***, for example:

```
[x for x if a_list if x == 1]
```

is preferable to

```
map(lambda x: x == 1, a_list)
```

as well as

```
class MySuperAwesomeClass:
    pass

def my_super_function():
    pass
```

is preferable to

```
class my_super_awesome_class:
    pass

def mySuperFunction()
    pass
```

This way, especially in a team of developers or in an open source project with multiple contributors, there is a kind of convention which everybody follows to make others life 
easier.